# disabled submit button after submitting form data to server. in react native

Tags: forms, react-native, form-submit

I am new to react native. I have created a form from where I am sending some data to server. Now I want that to disabled submit button after user click on submit . once user submit data then after He unable to send data. means I want to avoid duplicate entry. please help. thanks. if possible also tell how to do it with functional component too.

here is my code

```
export default function Add(props) {


  const { navigation } = props
  const offset = (Platform.OS === 'android') ? -200 : 0;
  

  const [AmazonError, setAmazonError] = useState([]);
  const [Amazon, setAmazon] = useState('');
  const [AmazonCNError, setAmazonCNError] = useState([]);
  const [AmazonCN, setAmazonCN] = useState('');
  const [AEPSError, setAEPSError] = useState([]);
  const [AEPS, setAEPS] = useState('');
  const [DMTError, setDMTError] = useState([]);
  const [DMT, setDMT] = useState('');
  const [BBPSError, setBBPSError] = useState([]);
  const [BBPS, setBBPS] = useState('');

  const [leadTagNumber, setLeadTagNumber] = useState([]);

  const validateInputs = () => {

    if (!Amazon.trim()) {
      setAmazonError('Please Fill The Input')
      return;
    }
    if (!AmazonCN.trim()) {
      setAmazonCNError('Please Fill The Input')
      return;
    }
    if (!AEPS.trim()) {
      setAEPSError('Please Fill The Input')
      return;
    }
    if (!DMT.trim())   {
      setDMTError('Please Fill The Input')
      return;
    }
    if (!BBPS.trim()) { 
      setBBPSError('Please Fill The Input')
      return;
    }
    else 
    {

        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=submitting form data to api start+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
{
  
    const leadTagNumber = props.route.params.leadTagNumber


    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by",'leadTagNumber']).then(response => {
  //     console.log(response[0][0]) // Key1
       console.log(response[0][1]) // Value1
  //     console.log(response[1][0]) // Key2
       console.log(response[1][1]) // Value2
       console.log(leadTagNumber)


  fetch('https://xyxtech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata/tbservice_details', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
      body: JSON.stringify([{  data}])
    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      Alert.alert("File uploaded");
      return response.json();
    });
  });
  // event.preventDefault();
  }
  //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++submitting form data to api end++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

      Alert.alert("success")
      return;
//}
    }
  };

    const handleAmazon = (text) => {
    setAmazonError('')
    setAmazon(text)
    }
    const handleAmazonCN= (text) => {
      setAmazonCNError('')
      setAmazonCN(text)
    }
    const handleAEPS= (text) => {
    setAEPSError('')
    setAEPS(text)
    }
    const handleDMT = (text) => {
      setDMTError('')
      setDMT(text)
      }
      const handleBBPS = (text) => {
        setBBPSError('')
        setBBPS(text)
        }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <ScrollView style={{flex: 1,}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>        

      

          <TextInput 
                        maxLength={30}
                        placeholder="AEPS (Adhar enabled payment system) *"
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(text)=>handleAEPS(text)}
                        defaultValue={AEPS}
                        value = {AEPS} />
          <Text>{AEPSError}</Text>
      
        

         </ScrollView>
        <Button
          style={styles.inputStyleB}
          title="Submit"
          color="#FF8C00"
          onPress={() => validateInputs()}
        />
        </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set new state property to enable/disable button

```
const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);
```

Now in your button component, add *disabled* property with *disableButton* state.

```
<Button
   style={styles.inputStyleB}
   title="Submit"
   color="#FF8C00"
   onPress={() => validateInputs()}
   disabled={disableButton}
/>
```

Disable you button before fetching data

```
setDisableButton(true) //Add this
const leadTagNumber = props.route.params.leadTagNumber
```

Incase of fetch error or after fetching is complete, enable button again

```
setDisabledButton(false)
```